# how to pass the pointer to a function and assign the value to the variable pointed to in C?

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-value

I know the c always pass by values, but if I have a pointer:

```
int  i = 4;
int * p;
p = &i;
```

then I have a function, how to pass pointer `p` to it and change the value of variable `i`?

```
void changeValue(int *p)
{
}
```

how to pass the pointer and change the variable pointed by `p`?

Comment: "I know the c always pass by values" How do you know this?

Comment: Thanks for that line buddy. I didn't knew that. I mean I knew that by experience that everything is copied, even pointer's values but never gave it a second thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple example shows how to pass a pointer (i.e. not a value) and recieve back through that pointer, the new value held by the integer.   Note the reduced number of variables.  i.e. there is no need necessarily to create a separate copy of `int *p;`.  Nor is it necessary in this case to initialize p:  `p = &i;` to the address of i.

```
int changeValue(int *);
int main(void)
{
    int i=15;
    changeValue(&i);
    return 0;
}

int changeValue(int *p) //prototyped to accept int *
{
    return *p = 3;  
}
```

If you do want to create a pointer in the first place, and pass that pointer, then:

```
int changeValue(int *);
int main(void)
{
    int i=15;
    int *p;
    p = &i;
    *p; // *p == 15 at this point
    //since p is already a pointer, just pass
    //it as is
    changeValue(p);
    return 0;
}

int changeValue(int *q) //prototyped to accept int *
{
    return *q = 3;  
}
```

It is important to note that your statement: `I know the c always pass by values` is not correct.  It is more common for functions to be written such that pointers are passed because often a pointer is smaller, and more efficient to pass around than the actual variable, especially when large arrays, or structs are used.  Keep in mind though that passing `&i` (the address of i) works just as well as passing `p` if passing a pointer is called for.

Answer (score 2):

Simply pass it by calling `changeValue` as

```
changeValue(p);
```

and change the value of variable pointed by it (`i`) by assigning a value to the `*p` in `changeValue()`

```
void changeValue(int *p)  
{
     *p = an int value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void changeValue( int* ) ;

int main( void )
{
    int  i = 4; // Suppose i is stored at address 1000h
    int * p;    
    p = &i;     // Now p stores the address of i that is 1000h

    changeValue(p); // Can also be written as changeValue(&i);
    // Here you are passing the address of i to changeValue function

    return 0 ;
}

void changeValue( int* p ) // Accept a parameter of type int*
{
    *p = 100 ; // store the value 100 at address 1000h
    return ;
}
```

Comment: probably good to mention if a function's first appearance _in C_ is not defined first with a specific return type, i.e. return type is left ambiguous, it is assumed by compiler that it will return int.  So that the first time `changeValue(p);` appears in main, because it is ambiguous, the compiler assumes `int`.  Then it is defined as `void changeValue(int *)` at function definition.  This results in _redeclaration of function_ compile time error.  Your code is perfect if you add prototype `void changeValue(int *);` somewhere before `main()`.  (I am not downvoter, but will upvote if fixed)

Comment: @alk :: My mistake. I answered this in a hurly-burly.

Comment: @ryyker :: Absolutely correct. Thanks for pointing me that out.

Answer (score 1):

```
int  i = 4;
int * p = &i;
changeValue(p);
printf("%d",*p);

void changeValue(int *p)
{
    *p = 5;
}
```

Full program - http://ideone.com/DCvhxE

Comment: Why not place this short (and correct) example code you linked into your answer? The answer as it states is not correct as it misses to prototype `changeValue()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you dereference the pointer in `changeValue` and assign to it, it will alter the value of `i` in the calling frame.

e.g.:

```
void changeValue(int *p)
{
    *p = 0;
}
```